# How to catch td index in Datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have datatable and trying to catch column+row index when user press on it:

```
$('#datatable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(){
    var eq = $(this).index(); 
    console.log(eq); 

});
```

So, I could catch index of row (tr) by this way. However, I need also column (td index) with it. Does anyone could advise some approach?

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36123337/datatable-column-onclick) of similar task, just from backside (when someone needs few catchers). I am not good enought in jquery to convert it to my trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen for `td` clicks and then get the indices of both the clicked `td` and it's parent `tr`:

```
$('#datatable tbody').on('click', 'td', function(){
    var clicked_td = $(this);
    var td_index = clicked_td.index(); 
    var tr_index = clicked_td.parent().index();
    console.log(td_index); 
    console.log(tr_index); 
});
```